# Error while installing truffle-hdwallet-provider

Tags: truffle, installation, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I am on windows OS and my current python version is 3.6 and node version is v10.12.0

I am trying to install truffle-hdwallet-provider by running following command:

```
npm install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider
```

Here is the error I am facing:

```
E:\BlockChain\truffle\firsttoken_deployment>npm install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider

> sha3@1.2.3 install E:\BlockChain\truffle\firsttoken_deployment\node_modules\sha3
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\BlockChain\truffle\firsttoken_deployment\node_modules\sha3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\BlockChain\truffle\firsttoken_deployment\node_modules\sha3
gyp ERR! node -v v10.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN firsttoken_deployment@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN firsttoken_deployment@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sha3@1.2.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sha3@1.2.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-23T12_38_15_766Z-debug.log
```

Can someone guide me what is happening wrong?

Comment: See this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47937/error-in-unboxing-truffle-react-on-windows to install some dependencies you need python 2 (you are using python 3 and it is failing).